# how to use select into to insert many records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have a stored procedure that will copy data from table A to table B and return id that is generated from table B to update table a record .
this is sample data 
table A is :

```
id----Name---refId---value----KPI 
 1    ahmed    550    50      30
 2    ali             30 
 3    soo      561    40      30
```

Table B is :

```
Id ---- Name ---- Value
550     ahmed       50
561     soo         30
```

i've tried the following 
i've defined a rec type

```
VAR_RECORD_A mySchema.A%rowtype;
refffId Number ;
BEGIN
select 
* 
into
VAR_RECORD_A 
from mySchema.A
where (value passed to function)=  var_kpi_element_req.BPM_KPI_ID ;
end ;
begin
insert into mySchema.B
(name , value)
Values 
(VAR_RECORD_A.name , VAR_RECORD_A.value)
RETURNING Id into refffId ;
end;

begin 
update A 
set refId = refffId 
where kpi =(value passed to function)
end;
```

my problem is the select into will return many records , i believe my code will work if only return 1 record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a Cursor loop:

```
    -- don't declare VAR_RECORD_A as rowtype ... 
    refffId Number ;
BEGIN
    for VAR_RECORD_A in ( -- instead make it a cursor ref 
        select * 
        from mySchema.A
        where (value passed to function)=  var_kpi_element_req.BPM_KPI_ID    
  ) 
  loop

    insert into mySchema.B
    (name , value)
    Values 
    (VAR_RECORD_A.name , VAR_RECORD_A.value)
    RETURNING Id into refffId ;

    update A 
    set refId = refffId 
    where kpi =(value passed to function)
    and a.PK = VAR_RECORD_A.pk -- identify current row of A for update

  end loop;
```

---

Note: I have removed the unnecessary BEGIN … END notations. Only declare nested blocks when there's real value in doing so.

In real life I would want to make this bulk operation more efficient by using collections and forall statements for a set-based approach.

Also I would consider whether I needed to lock the selected rows from `A` FOR UPDATE OF KPI, in case my whole transaction failed due to another session having a lock on one row. Doing this would allow you to use the WHERE CURRENT OF syntax when updating `A`.

Comment: shouldn't i put the update statement outside the loop , 
because it will update many records at once ?

Comment: Ah you're right to point out that problem, I'd overlooked it. So the thing is your query of `A` returns multiple rows. So you insert multiple rows into `B`, returning **multiple instances** of `refffid`: which value of `refffid` do you want to use when updating `A`? My assumption is that you want to update the record of `A` which provided the values of `name , value` inserted into `B`. But to do that you need to provide a key for the update statement. I will amend my answer.

Comment: every row will have one row in the other table 
and the Id in table B is db sequence

Comment: Don't know whether you read my original comment or the edited version. Anyway I have amended my question

Answer (score -1):

Think this would be better...

```html
DECLARE @VarA TABLE
 (

 id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name nVARCHAR(100),
 refId INT,
 value INT,
 KPI INT
 )

DECLARE @VarB TABLE
 (
 id INT IDENTITY(5,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name nVARCHAR(100),
 value INT
 )

DECLARE @output TABLE
 (
  id INT,
  Name nVARCHAR(100)
 )

INSERT INTO @VarA
(Name, refId, value, KPI)
VALUES
('ahmed',550,50,  30),
('ali', NULL, 30, NULL),
('soo',  561,40,  30)

INSERT INTO @VarB
(Name, value)
VALUES
('ahmed', 50),
('soo', 30)

MERGE INTO @VarB AS Target  
USING (SELECT Name, Value FROM @VarA) AS Source (Name, Value)  
ON Target.Name = Source.Name  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
 UPDATE SET Value = Source.Value --Do you want to update the value if record exists? 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
 INSERT (Name, Value) VALUES (Name, Value)  
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Name INTO @output(ID, Name);

UPDATE a SET refId = o.ID FROM @VarA a
INNER JOIN @output o ON o.Name = a.Name

SELECT * FROM @VarA
```

Comment: thanks for your answer mr Koen 
but i think this code will only work with Microsoft SQL ,

Comment: This question is tagged `[oracle]` and requires an answer using Oracle syntax. For future reference questions tagged `[sql]` refer to the generic SQL language. Questions about MS SQL Server RDBMS will be tagged `[sql-server]` or maybe with a version such as `[sql-server-2008]`.

Comment: My bad. Did not see this. Looks like MERGE is supported in Oracle though:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9016.htm

Comment: Really not clear why you think MERGE is the solution to the problem. Also Oracle doesn't support INNER JOIN with UPDATE so this answer requires a bunch reworking before it will fly with Oracle.